# QQ Plot question related to trading

Tags: r, qq-plot

I'm kicking the tires of DSP and don't fully understand the tools. I built an algorithmic trading system and decided to do a Q-Q plot of the signal to noise ratio against the **average** return for each bin to see if I could eliminate some losing trades.

[image: QQ Plot of signal to noise ratio vs mean return]

The conclusions that I drew from this are:

- The distribution is fat-tailed
- The x-intercept is SNR = 0.10. If I eliminate trades where the SNR < 0.1, the mean return is 0.0004. The mean return for SNR >= 0.1 is 0.0001. I would have expected the opposite based on the Q-Q plot.

Since the distribution is fat tailed, is there any simple filter that I can add to focus on the profitable, right tail?

What else is this plot saying?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't 'eliminate trades where the SNR < 0.1'  and 'SNR >= 0.1' mean the same thing? I am curious.

If you wanted to consider top 50 - percentile trade, just subset for the top 50 percentile directly, I guess.

The quantile-quantile (q-q) plot is a graphical technique for determining if two data sets come from populations with a common distribution. How do you wish to find out winning trades by contrasting SNR and percentage return. Isn't that like a 2D scatter plot or something?

Comment: I was looking to see if SNR values above/below that value made a difference. I expected above 0.0001 to have stronger returns based on the qq plot, but the opposite was true.

Comment: Good point on looking for common distributions. One thing I should consider is the skew around the inflection point since it may not be symmetric

Comment: For starters, try the histograms of both the variables, before plotting them together.

After reading your question, I looked up in the internet. I still not understand how Q-Q plots can be used to compare two variables. I was of the opinion that Q-Q plot compares two distributions, as mentioned here: http://onlinestatbook.com/2/advanced_graphs/q-q_plots.html